# how to iterate through a list of dictionaries, printing each dictionary to a new line in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to iterate through a list of dictionaries in Python, and for each dictionary present all the key:value pairs. I want to print each dictionary on it's own line, as well as count the line entries.

```
list_dict = [{'name':'d1', 'color':'red'},{'name':'d2', 'color':'green'},{'name':'d3','color':'blue}]
```

when I use

```
for i in list_dict:
    print(i)
```

I get a very 'ugly' printout (including brackets and quotation marks)
However, when I try to use a nested loop:

```
for i in list_dict:
    for key, val in i.items():
        print(key, ':', val, end=" ")
```

the code will print ALL THE DATA FROM ALL DICTIONARIES in the same line.
I am looking for a way to print each dictionaries keys and values on a new line.
Additionally, I would like to also number the lines (1. key:value, key:value) etc. Since i becomes a dictionary and not an integer, printing i does not work. I was sort of able to go around this by wrapping the whole thing in ANOTHER for loop

```
for i in range(len(list_dict)):
 (some code)
```

but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do all of this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting):

```py
list_dict = [
    {'name':'d1', 'color':'red'}, {'name':'d2', 'color':'green'}, {'name':'d3','color':'blue'},
    {'name':'d4', 'color':'red'}, {'name':'d5', 'color':'green'}, {'name':'d6','color':'blue'}
]

for i, list_item in enumerate(list_dict):
    print(f"{i + 1}. ", end='')
    for j, key in enumerate(list_item.keys()):
        print(f"{key}:{list_item[key]}{'' if j == len(list_item) - 1 else ', '}", end='')
    print("")
```

Output:

```
1. name:d1, color:red
2. name:d2, color:green
3. name:d3, color:blue
4. name:d4, color:red
5. name:d5, color:green
6. name:d6, color:blue
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
j = 1
for i in list_dict:
    print(j, end= " ")
    for key, val in i.items():
        print(key, ':', val, end=" ")
    print('')
    j += 1
```

This is far from the most elegant and/or optimized solution, but it works for the case stated.

Comment: So the issue with this one is that it adds a line break between each dictionary line...

Comment: @tzvik15 you can replace `print('\n')` with `print('')` to fix that. By the way, my solution doesn't have such an issue :)

Comment: I've just edited the answer to remove the unwanted line break. It should be fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

For Printing Each Dictionary to New Line:

```
list_dict = [{'name':'d1', 'color':'red'},{'name':'d2', 'color':'green'},{'name':'d3','color':'blue'}]
itr=1
for i in list_dict:
    print(itr, end=' ')
    for key, val in i.items():
        print(key, ':', val, end=' ')
    print()
    itr=itr+1
```

Output:
[image]
for print data in new line you can do

```
for i in list_dict:
    for key, val in i.items():
        print(key, ':', val, end="\n")
```

also remove `end=" "`

```
for i in list_dict:
    for key, val in i.items():
        print(key, ':', val)
```

For print data of dictionary like 1:key:value

```
itr=1
for i in list_dict:
    for key, val in i.items():
        print(itr,':',key, ':', val, end="\n")
        itr=itr+1
```

Complete Code

```
list_dict = [{'name':'d1', 'color':'red'},{'name':'d2', 'color':'green'},{'name':'d3','color':'blue'}]
itr=1
for i in list_dict:
    for key, val in i.items():
        print(itr,':',key, ':', val)
        itr=itr+1
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I believe OP wants `name` and `color` on the same line, as it's mentioned on their sample.

Comment: was just about to ask that! :)